# Use git to compare two forks of code, show differences

Tags: git, linux-kernel, diff

I would like to compare two sources for kernels, for example the kernel for the Nexus 10 (https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/exynos.git) and for the ARM Chromebook (https://git.chromium.org/git/chromiumos/third_party/kernel.git)

Can anyone descibe the a command that would do this?

Answer (score 2):

Making the diff between two directories is not a git specific operation :

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/exynos.git exynos
git clone https://git.chromium.org/git/chromiumos/third_party/kernel.git chromiumos

# use your favorite diff tool to compare both directories :
meld exynos/ chromiumos/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clone one repo, then add the other as a remote and fetch it. Then do a diff between their two `master` branches:

```bash
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/exynos.git

cd exynos
git remote add kernel https://git.chromium.org/git/chromiumos/third_party/kernel.git
git fetch kernel

git diff master kernel/master
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply using diff. Clone the required sources you want, then do the following:

```
   diff -uprN exynos/ chromiumos/
```

Above command will create unified (-u) patch, will show c function names (-p), recursively traverse the directories (-r), if any file missing will treat it as new file (-N).